# Processing data with image in jsf / primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Well, I have a "hard" work to do, i'll try explain it.

My classes envolved in this are: Car and Problem. One Car can have a lot of Problem (1:N). Let's imagine that i have to trade the wheel's Car, so:

I have a "generic car image" that have 4 wheel (like all cars in the world). This image will poup-up to user, and this user can choose 1 wheel (clicking in this wheel) and automatically the system will know what is the exact wheel that have problem (front-left, front-right, back-right, back-left). In this way i avoid the user to choose in a selectOneMenu the wheel with problem, he can choose the wheel in image.

How can i do it ? This is possible ?

Comment: Of course you can. **BUT** can you show us what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I didn't try nothing because i have no ideia how start it and what component use.

Comment: Have a look at http://primefaces.org/showcase for all primefaces components so that you will get an idea where to start and what components can be used.

Comment: yeah. i looked everything in showcase but i didn't find nothing to solve my problem.

Comment: it's not a jsf work, You need to map the wheels in the map using html tag, then with each click call a back-end function(servlet) and give the response.

Comment: oh. good solution @user2511414. I'll study more about "map tag", but i think that i can solve it with this tag. Thanks.

Comment: if you want to do it with JSF, so you need to impl your own tag and use it in the pages, but if you ask me, I prefer Servlet over JSF

Comment: User 2511414 is babbling nonsense because he never really used/understood JSF. Just ignore him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the image in blocks by a graphic editor and put them in links.

E.g.

```
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.setWheel(1)}">
    <p:graphicImage name="wheel1.png" />
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.setWheel(2)}">
    <p:graphicImage name="wheel2.png" />
</p:commandLink>
<br />
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.setWheel(3)}">
    <p:graphicImage name="wheel3.png" />
</p:commandLink>
<p:commandLink actionListener="#{bean.setWheel(4)}">
    <p:graphicImage name="wheel4.png" />
</p:commandLink>
```

You could also use a table (`<h:panelGrid>`) for this. Throw if necessary some CSS to make them block elements without padding/margin/etc so that it look like 1 image.

Comment: Is there a better/easier solution then? Tell how you would have the generated HTML to look like, then we can tell how to write JSF in such way that it generates exactly the desired HTML.

Comment: The important is i understood the logic and now i can do it alone. thanks. @BalusC